# How to replace with multiple characters in php?

Tags: php, axios

I try to replace a character, here is a newline but the user can put spaces for example. When I put the variable it doesn't work. If I use double quotes and put the character it works. I submit the data with axios.

Don't works:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$converted = str_replace($data["find"], $data["replace"], $data["content"]);
echo json_encode(["final"=>$converted]);
```

It works:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$converted = str_replace("\n", $data["replace"], $data["content"]);
echo json_encode(["final"=>$converted]);
```

How can i make it work with variable?

Comment: Start with `var_dump($data["find"])`.

Comment: I'd say var_dump it all.

Comment: string(2) "\n" in the console

Comment: array(3) {
  ["content"]=>
  string(64) "asdasdasd
asdasdasd
asdassdasd
asdasdasdasd
adasdasasd
asdasdasd"
  ["find"]=>
  string(2) "\n"
  ["replace"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}

Comment: maybe i need to transform the content

Comment: but in the response is with newline not the code just enter

Comment: Just tested your code. It works as expected : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/137bc9263a6150e840d4fe1ac2eb982368e5fa4c .

Comment: then i have a problem i the data array  :(

Comment: when I war dump the content don't have the \n just the enter is not the code, from textarea I send newline normal

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution don't know is the best.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

$converted = str_replace($data["find"], $data["replace"], json_encode($data["content"]));

echo json_encode(["final"=>json_decode($converted)]);
```

The problem was str_replace don't found in the content \n json_encode converts newline in code.